# R correct usage of Grouping Likert

Tags: r

I am trying to get the grouping option to work.
When I select grouping I get erroneous data. Here is my code

```
> likert(GroupCD[16])
  Item Strongly Disagree Disagree  Neutral    Agree Strongly Agree
1  Q16                 0        0 10.71429 46.42857       42.85714
> likert(GroupCD[16],grouping = GroupCD$Group)
  Group Item Strongly Disagree Disagree  Neutral Agree Strongly Agree
1     C  Q16          6.666667 33.33333 60.00000     0              0
2     D  Q16         15.384615 61.53846 23.07692     0              0
```

As is is possible to see the values when separated by group are wrong, or maybe (and probably) I am using this wrong.

Here is the group column

```
> print(GroupCD$Group)
 [1] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D"
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Here is GroupCD[16]

```
    "Q16"
    "1" "Strongly Agree"
    "2" "Strongly Agree"
    "3" "Strongly Agree"
    "4" "Strongly Agree"
    "5" "Agree"
    "6" "Agree"
    "7" "Strongly Agree"
    "8" "Strongly Agree"
    "9" "Agree"
    "10"    "Strongly Agree"
    "11"    "Strongly Agree"
    "12"    "Neutral"
    "13"    "Strongly Agree"
    "14"    "Agree"
    "15"    "Agree"
    "16"    "Neutral"
    "17"    "Strongly Agree"
    "18"    "Strongly Agree"
    "19"    "Agree"
    "20"    "Agree"
    "21"    "Agree"
    "22"    "Agree"
    "23"    "Agree"
    "24"    "Strongly Agree"
    "25"    "Agree"
    "26"    "Neutral"
    "27"    "Agree"
    "28"    "Agree"
```

Comment: A sample of the data in `GroupCD[16]` would be helpful to understand what's going on in your case.

Comment: My bad =/ I've just edited

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your results.
Check the class of the `Q16` and `group`, if they are of class "ordered", try changing them to "factor" (with no order) then try `likert` again.

Comment: Hey so GroupCD[16] is Factor w/ 5 levels the way it should be. Group is char maybe here is the problem?

Comment: I don't think so. Try running again the function in a fresh R session, I just can't replicate your output. I get the proper values by group.

Comment: Hey @JuanBosco I've updated the likert package and opened a new session and it worked! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can close this:
Apparently it was a problem with garbage in the R workspace/session (??). Once I've started with a fresh one everything worked fine